# Umlauts with PHP and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, char

I am facing a problem with Umlauts and PHP / MSSQL.

On php I have to following code:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset','Latin1_General_CI_AS');

$dbhandle = mssql_connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx') or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");
mssql_select_db('xxx', $dbhandle);
$stmt = mssql_init('ESY_GetPriceVP', $dbhandle);
//Item Code with Umlaut
$itemId = 'HE51grün';

mssql_bind($stmt, '@itemId',  $itemId,  SQLVARCHAR);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);

if (!mssql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'Keine Datensaetze gefunden<br>';
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_rows($result); ++$i) {
        echo 'Preis fuer Artikel ',mssql_result($result, $i, 'Amount');
    }
}
```

I am executing a stored procedure `ESY_GetPriceVP` that finds the price of  item by the `itemId`.
If I have an `itemId` without an umlaut its doing fine.

In the procedure I am converting the `itemId` to nvarchar:
`convert (nvarchar(50), @itemId)`

The complete stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ESY_GetPriceVP] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
    @itemId nvarchar(20) = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @pricegroup VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @subsegment VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @pricePricegroup NUMERIC(28,12);
    DECLARE @pricePriceSegment NUMERIC(28,12);
    DECLARE @priceLineDisc NUMERIC(28,12);

    SET @pricegroup = 'VP';
    --Set @itemId = 'HE51grün'; 
    --= convert (nvarchar(50), @itemId)
    SELECT 
        @pricePricegroup = MIN(PRICEDISCTABLE.AMOUNT)
    FROM PRICEDISCTABLE
    WHERE PRICEDISCTABLE.DATAAREAID = 'vv'
        AND PRICEDISCTABLE.ITEMRELATION = convert (nvarchar(50), @itemId)
        AND PRICEDISCTABLE.ACCOUNTRELATION = @pricegroup
        AND ( GETDATE() >= PRICEDISCTABLE.FROMDATE OR PRICEDISCTABLE.FROMDATE = '01-01-1900' )
        AND ( PRICEDISCTABLE.TODATE < '01-01-1901' OR GETDATE() <= PRICEDISCTABLE.TODATE )
        AND (PRICEDISCTABLE.QUANTITYAMOUNT = 1 OR PRICEDISCTABLE.QUANTITYAMOUNT = 0)

    SELECT  CASE WHEN @pricePricegroup IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @pricePricegroup END AS Amount
END
```

If I uncomment '--Set @itemId = 'HE51grün';' the statements returns the correct price. 
I spend so much time in finding a solution - hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever tried to set a charset for the connection at runtime? UTF-8 should work.

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

You can set this setting directly in php.ini, if you want so.

Maybe you have to play with `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` in addition.

---

Hast Du mal probiert, das Charset für die Verbindung zu setzen? UTF-8 sollte da funktionieren.

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Das kannst Du auch direkt in der php.ini setzen, dann gilt das für alle Verbindungen auf dem Server.

Vielleicht brauchst Du zusätzlich `utf8_decode` und `utf8_encode`, damit das passt (für jeden String dann).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - i tried both. But its just trying, not knowing :)